# Add colons to mac address using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a mac address looking like this `482C6A1E593D` and I want to return it into something like this `48:2C:6A:1E:59:3D`

I have been able to make this code:

```
Pattern.compile("(.{2})").matcher(macAddress).replaceAll("$1:");
```

However it returns `48:2C:6A:1E:59:3D:` instead of `48:2C:6A:1E:59:3D` I would like to ignore the last match to avoid having the last :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also use a positive lookahead requiring a symbol to be present:

```
String macAddress = "482C6A1E593D";
System.out.println(macAddress.replaceAll(".{2}(?=.)", "$0:"));
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/qn2xsn)

Note you do not need any capturing groups here since `$0` is a backreference to the whole match (same can be used with [TheLostMind's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39660058/3832970) - use `s.replaceAll("\\w{2}(?!$)", "$0:")`).

Comment: Yes. You are right using `$0` without capturing group would also have done it :)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a negative look head for end of String.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "482C6A1E593D";
    s = s.replaceAll("(\\w{2})(?!$)", "$1:");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

O/P :

```
48:2C:6A:1E:59:3D
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin** version of [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39660154/421467)'s answer:

```kotlin
val macAddress = "482C6A1E593D"
println(macAddress.replace(".{2}(?=.)".toRegex(), "$0:"))
```